# ajax отправить json формат и принять на стороне сервера

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

```
const json = {
  "buttonOrder": btn,
  "id": idForm
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'func.php',
    data: {
      data: JSON.stringify(json)
    }
  });
```

Как мне принять data на сервере?

Comment: юрл сервера какой / как ты этот пхп файл запускаешь?

Comment: в этом же корне находится файл. До этого я запускал код так if (isset($_POST['name']){...}
Перед отправкой в data: { name: 'username' }

Comment: Я имею ввиду, ты `OpenServer` или что-то похожее юзаешь, чтобы у тебя .php файл работал..?

Comment: Да использую Open Server

Comment: Url поменяй на `http://localhost: (тут твой порт сервера) /func.php`

Answer (score 0):

На сервере в func.php все, что вы отдали ajax'ом будет находиться в переменной $_POST[data]

Не совсем понятен вопрос - не понимаете как на стороне func.php получить то, что отдал ajax, или не получается достучаться до func.php?

Какие-то ошибки выдает? 
попробуй добавить в ajax запрос

```
 response: 'text',
 success:function (data) { 
     console.log(data);
     }
```

тогда после выполнения ajax-а в консоли будет ответ от func.php (если в func.php прописан какой-нибудь скрипт, который отвечает - echo(), print_r() и проч...
Можно прям в начале скрипта прописать `echo($_POST[data]);` и если в консоли браузера выпадет ваш json, то ваш скрипт успешно получил ваш JSON и он в $_POST[data]